# How can I get an overview of COM ports on a Windows computer?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, com, com-port

How can I see both physical and virtual COM ports that have been installed and configured on a Windows computer? Can I see the settings and services they have been assigned to, or do I have to go the other way around and look for services with assigned COM ports? Is there no single Windows utility or control panel applet that will give you an overview of all of this in a single program window?

Answer (score 0):

Might be mistaken, but doesn't **Device Manager** (My Computer >> Properties >> Hardware >> Device Manager, or something like that, as I'm currently on XP) show all COM ports?

For the settings and services part, I think it is a per-application basis, as it wouldn't be logic for Windows to track all that information.

Comment: Yeah, I guess... nothing ever is logical in Windows. This new Windows, Windows 8, takes the prize as the worst Windows yet. Anyway... This type of thing is registered with the operating system, not really with the program you're using, be it it's stored as registry keys or by other means.

Comment: But I seem to remember that there was a Windows utility or control panel applet that would show you any virtual or in fact all COM ports available and associated Windows services. But I don't remember how to bring it up. Any idea? It's probably buried deep down in some strange way as a sub-menu somewhere. Yes, Device Manager will show any present physical COM ports. It also gives you a way of setting global COM port settings like bitrate, parity and flow control. But will it also show any emulated COM ports?... like USB to COM port?

Comment: To the last question - yes, it will.

Comment: No COM ports at all being shown on my Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 once you plug the device into the RS232 to USB adapter it should be 'seen' by Windows. But it doesn't show data of emulated COM ports.
In this case I'm using software for catching and analyzing data from all COM-ports. It's easier then Windows system solution and you can choose how you want to get the data.